# Free JSON Parser (python)

Tags: python, json

I have a file that JSON statements that look like this

```
20110812 09:00:00:012000 INFO - #JSON{"name": "YMean", "args": {"timestamp": "1313157600012", "YMean": "[15770.064851138422]
```

. I need a python parser that will parse a whole file that consists of this kind of JSON statements.Any suggests what would be most useful and easy to use?
Thanks

Comment: Please accept answers to your questions by clicking the check mark next to the best one. You've now asked __ten questions__ and not accepted a single answer. Go back and accept the most helpful answer to each of you old questions, and people will me more likely to give you good answers in the future!

Comment: @Trup you have all your questions on your profile page: http://stackoverflow.com/users/869986/trup , you can enter the questions and mark them as answered from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet possibly is the official Python JSON-library. Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) to see how you can parse your JSON-data, it is very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import json
>>> corpus = '''20110812 09:00:00:012000 INFO - #JSON{"name": "YMean", "args": {"timestamp": "1313157600012", "YMean": "[15770.064851138422]"}}'''
>>> junk, data = corpus.split("#JSON")
>>> json.loads(data)
{u'args': {u'timestamp': u'1313157600012', u'YMean': u'[15770.064851138422]'}, u'name': u'YMean'}
```

Comment: `[json.dumps(line.split('#JSON', 1)[1]) for line in file('foo')]`?

Comment: Use `load` instead of `loads` to read from a file rather than a string. (You get no points for guessing what the `s` in `loads` stands for.) @TokenMacGuy if each line is a separate JSON object, then sure; but normally the file is really a single JSON array.

Comment: I think TMG meant to use 'loads' (convert JSON to Python object) rather than 'dumps' (convert Python object to JSON string).

Comment: Say I do x = [json.dumps(line.split('#JSON', 1)[1]) for line in file('foo')]. How do I actually parse x with JSON then?

Comment: You just did.  `json.dumps` is json parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't seem to be a json statement. You seem to have a log file where (some of the ?) log messages happen to contain json. You will find no json parser that handles this, simply because that isn't json. So you will need to process the lines one by one and extract the json part (see TokenMacGuy's answer for a simple solution), and then just use the stdlib's `json` module.